# Is it possible to run Cloud Dataflow with custom packages?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to provision Dataflow workers with custom packages?
I'd like to shell out to a Debian-packaged binary from inside a computation.

Edit: To be clear, the package configuration is sufficiently complex that it's not feasible to just bundle the files in --filesToStage. 
The solution should involve installing the Debian package at some point.

Answer (score 4):

This is not something Dataflow explicitly supports. However, below are some suggestions on how you could accomplish this. Please keep in mind that things could change in the service that could break this in the future.

There are two separate problems:

1. Getting the debian package onto the worker.
2. Installing the debian package.

For the first problem you can use --filesToStage and specify the path to your debian package. This will cause the package to be uploaded to GCS and then downloaded to the worker on startup. If you use this option you must include in the value of --filesToStage all your jars as well since they will not be included by default if you explicitly set --filesToStage.

On the java worker any files passed in --filesToStage will be available in the following directories (or a subdirectory of)

```
/var/opt/google/dataflow
```

or

```
/dataflow/packages
```

You would need to check both locations in order to be guaranteed of finding the file.

**We provide no guarantee that these directories won't change in the future. These are simply the locations used today.**

To solve the second problem you can override [StartBundle](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn) in your [DoFn](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn). From here you could shell out to the command line and install your debian package after finding it in /dataflow/packages.

There could be multiple instances of your DoFn running side by side so you could get contention issues if two processes try to install your package simultaneously. I'm not sure if the debian package system can handle this or you need to so in your code explicitly.

A slight variant of this approach is to not use --filesToStage to distribute the package to your workers but instead add code to your startBundle to fetch it from some location.

Comment: Thanks! What environment do the workers live in? Is there an image I can play with? Also, is there a way to ensure each instance runs no more than one worker at a time?

Comment: There is no way to ensure an instance only runs a single worker at a time. I'm not sure what you mean by environment. Each worker runs inside its own docker container.  If you run your job with --teardownPolicy=TEARDOWN_NEVER your VMs will remain running after your job completes so you can ssh in an poke around. However, you won't see /dataflow because that directory only exists inside the container.

Comment: Hello from the future! Where is the docker container defined and how is it invoked? I figure I should be able to run it on my own local machine and see what's inside.

Comment: The docker container is part of the Dataflow service. Running it on your local machine is not something we support or encourage. If you really want to inspect the container a recent container is available in our Google Container Registry  dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/java-batch:20160118-rc01.  If you're having trouble installing your binary, we might be able to help if you tell us what problem you are hitting.