# In Cloud Dataflow, how do I inspect the Docker container in which a worker runs?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How do I get shell access to the Docker container in which a Dataflow worker runs?

As mentioned in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095433/is-it-possible-to-run-cloud-dataflow-on-custom-instances), we can set `teardownPolicy=TEARDOWN_NEVER` to keep a worker VM around after a pipeline finishes.
This allows us to SSH into the host VM, but it doesn't insert us into the Docker container in which worker tasks run.
How do I get shell access to that container?

Context: I'd like to shell out to a Docker container inside my worker, but the `docker` binary does not appear to be available inside the worker container.
I've attempted to install Docker in the container, but I'm hitting errors, and it's slow to have to start a new pipeline just to test the next command.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is not installed inside the worker container.

There's currently not much support baked into Dataflow for starting Docker containers from within your worker.

However I think the following command can be used to create a shell in a running container

```
# List containers and their IDs
docker ps -notrunc
# Grab the process id of the container
PID=$(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' my_container_id)
# Get an interactive shell on the container
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```